# getUserMedia Error webRTC

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia

I'm starting with webRTC and am trying to access to my camera, however, the code doesn't work, although there is no mistakes in it.

The code is:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||           
                               navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia 
                            || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
if (navigator.getUserMedia){
    var constrains ={video:true};
    function successCallback(localMediaStream){
        var video = document.querySelector("video");
        window.stream = localMediaStream;
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
        video.onloadedmetadata =function(e){
            video.play();
        }
    }
    function errorCallback(error){
        console.log("Error: ",error);
    }
    navigator.getUserMedia(constrains,successCallback,errorCallback);
}else{
    alert('Sorry, the browser you are using doesn\'t support getUserMedia');
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: what kind of error are you getting, and in what browser?

Comment: There is'nt errors but it doesn't turn on the camera, I'm working in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am guessing that the code above is put in a html file and accessed directly by clicking on file( and url being like `file:///...`), this way would work in firefox, but **not in chrome**, for camera capture to work on chrome, you need to **host** the file in some server.

also, on an unrelated note, you can replace

```
    video.onloadedmetadata =function(e){
        video.play();
    }
```

with simply

```
    video.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not obvious whether you have a valid HTML5 video element to set the stream on. If you do, you can use the developer tools to verify the stream has been set on the source.

If you have a web server on your development machine, you can host your code that way, and view it 'locally'.